# How can you write/delete/read a file in a different user account with the same ip address with python?

Tags: python, file, networking

Recently, I learnt how to write/delete/read a file in Python (I am a beginner). However, something has got me thinking: is it possible to write/delete/read a file  in a different user account from the same network (i.e same ip address)? If so, how? Don't worry, I'll just try it at home. ;)

Comment: Hi @Nutella, from your question it is not clear what network environment you are on. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202326/read-remote-file-with-access-permissions which may be answering your question. Please make sure when asking a question to give all relevant information. You could check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove the file without Python, then you can remove it with Python. Otherwise, the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

This is running into more of an OS question. The answer is if you have permission to do so then yes you can but if you do not have permissions over the file then you cannot.